# Remote Commands fail after adding machines to TrustedHosts

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I added both local and remote machine to TrustedHosts:

```
winrm set winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="WIN-XXXXX,Windows7-1"}'
```

After doing that remote commands now fail

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "Windows7-1" -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {Rename-Computer -ComputerName 'Windows7-1' -NewName 'XXXX' -Force -PassThru -Restart }
```

If I wait for 2 mins and run same code it will work fine...

Comment: What's your error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$hostName="DomainName" 
$winrmPort = "5986"
$username = "Username"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “Password” -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“$username”, $secpasswd)
$soptions = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostName -ScriptBlock { Command Session } -Port $winrmPort -Credential $mycreds -SessionOption $soptions -UseSSL
```